# Why image changes when imported to eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, png

First I should say that I'm completely new to android so maybe my question is very ordinary for you.

**Problem** : I've designed the following image (png-24 with transparent background) in the `Photoshop` 
[image]

and added it to the `res/drawable` in my project to use it as the source of a `ImageButton` but it appears like this:
[image]

As you see the rounded shape has changed completely and a gray background is added to the image.
**Please** tell me how can I fix this? Is the way that I've used this image wrong or the image format or some thing else?

**Edit**:  I just resized the image(simple png) as I've added to my post and suddenly a corner of the image appeared,isn't it due to size or something like that?

[image]

This is the layout of the containing activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/showHistBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/showhistory" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/findWordBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/find_aword" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/insertNewWordBtn"
        android:layout_width="315dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/insertnewword" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `png-24 with transparent background` does not exist in nature. If you have transparency, then it's a 32 bit PNG (8 bit per Alpha channel, 8 per R channel, 8 per G channel and 8 per B channel). So, there lies the problem.

Comment: You mean if I save the output as png-8 or jpg it gets fixed?

Comment: JPG doesn't support ANY transparency. png-32 (8 bit per channel) will do the trick.

Comment: If you are used to PhotoShop, it will be a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Vyger: Isn't photoshop suited to my issue?

Comment: Sure, it is! No worry, use it.

Comment: It would also be useful if you sow your layout, because some problems can reside there. And using a 9 patch is a good advice.

Comment: @Vyger: I saved it as png-8 but nothing changed.

Comment: @Vyger: I've just updated the post.

Comment: OK I saved the image (the first one was good, Just misunderstood - Photoshop calls them 24 bit pngs improperly, because it then saves them to 32 bit)... 1 - The text souldn't be hardcoded (use one image as a TextView background and overlay the text on it, also dynamically). 2 - The image is cut too early (you don't leave enough space for the shadow, especially on the bottom part). 3 - Yes, this is elegible to become a 9 patch.

Comment: @Vyger: I'm changing the size and will report the result.

Comment: Let me see what is it now.

Comment: OK, my advice: smoothen the corners (use antialiasing). A higher resolution might also help (72 dpi is really poor). Consider that the lowest resolution device in Android has 120 dpi... and the normal is 160 dpi...

Comment: @Vyger: Thanks again,I was exactly trying this(increasing the dpi to 160).

Comment: I made a 9 patch (quickly, not really carefully) and the results aren't too disgusting. Now I have only 1 image as the background for 2 differently shaped buttons (inverted width and height proportions) and with different texts.

Comment: @Vyger: Didn't work again,I think I should try 9 patch.

Comment: I posted an answer, just to show you how a 9 patch works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added these to the `ImageButton` tag in the activity layout xml file and it fixed :)

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="0dp"
```

I found the answer completely by intuition but with trial and error found that none of the above statements should not get omitted (for future viewers).

Comment: This is true when you use src instead of background. You might also find  the other values of `scaleType` useful, in different occasions.

Comment: Now that I see your interface I can say, yes, in this case, it's the perfect solution for you, +1. But still please consider the use of 9 patches, for an overall optimization.

Comment: @Vyger: Thanks for advise, yes of course I should use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply draw a `9-patch` image with `Photoshop` drawing the shadows and put it into the `drawable` folders and set this in your `ImageButton` in xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_9patch_image"
```

I always do it by using Photoshop, it's super simple. For more details see this: [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: You mean simple png images won't show well in android?

Comment: With _png_ image you have to draw it with big dimension that occupy a lot of memory instead with _9-patch_ you can draw very small images that occupy a few kiloBytes. I always use _9-patch_ ;D

Comment: Thanks,it's really useful but I don't realize that is this problem (in appearance) due to png format?

Comment: PNG images are the best compromise for having good quality, transparency, but they aren't so much compressable. 9 patch allow to save some areas of wasted pixels by stretching some defined regions.

Answer (score 1):

After our long discussion in comments, see what a 9 patch can do (it's just to give you an idea of what you can really achive with just 1 image):

By using this image (/res/drawable/my_btn.9.png):

[image]

I got this result

[image]

You'll notice that the text isn't well centered: it's because I was in a hurry, and didn't make it perfect (while resizing and black-bordering for 9 patch).
And the starting image wasn't high-quality.

I used a 16sp font, probably you'll use a 32sp or even a bigger one.

Note: mind the extension: .9.png

Comment: Oh I've found something really strange. I just resized the image(simple png) as I've added to my post and suddenly a corner of the image appeared would you please look at the post again and see isn't it due to size or something like that?

Comment: I even appeared completely (but a compressed) when I added : android:scaleX="0.5". Now I think it's all about the width and height.

Comment: Normally, you would use `layout_width="wrap_content"` (and so layout_height). sometimes you'd prefer "match_parent". RARELY, you'd prefer a fixed size in dp. Also note the difference between `src` and `background`: src does NOT stretch your image, while background does.